# AWS Glue Job sometimes cannot resolve '`xxx`' given input columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

When I execute the aws glue job, the sql query statement which run successfully in Athena will report an error here, and it seems that there is a problem with their single quotes through the log.
Does anyone know what's going on here?

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`security_type`' given input columns: []; line 5 pos 0;
```

'GlobalLimit 100
+- 'LocalLimit 100
+- 'Project [test AS userid#40, test AS action#41, test AS datapoint_id#42, **'security_type** AS inv_type#43]
+- SubqueryAlias myDataSource
+- LogicalRDD false

Comment: you need to remove the backticks(`) and try running Glue job.

Comment: I have confirmed that my original sql does not contain double quotes, backticks(`), I want to find a suitable way to share sql. . It's really long and not very convenient to fit on this platform

Answer (score 0):

The reason for cannot resolve "column-name" is that the particular "column-name" doesn't exist in the dataframe in the sql-table.

It could also throw this error when you use double quotes("") for the column names in the query. Could you please give few more details if this doesn't work for you.

Thanks.

Comment: could you leave an email so that I could share the original sql and table definition for you?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running it the AWS glue check the tables.The tables you created for the it might in deprecated status.remove the table and create it from the begining.

if it is not working try creating crawler and give table prefix name along with the database name it will work for sure